# How to find matrix elements where the products of two rows are elements of a different matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, numerical-linear-algebra

I am considering a problem where I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $N\times N$ with complex elements. I know all of the elements of $A$, and I have a relation between the elements of $B$ and $A$:

$$
\prod_{k=1}^{N} B_{ik}B_{jk}=A_{ij} \quad \forall i, j \in \{1,2,\ldots,N\}
$$

In other words, the element $A_{ij}$ is equal to the product of the elements of the $i$th row and $j$th row of $B$.

Is there a method to solve for the elements of $B$? I am familiar with problems involving matrix-matrix and matrix-vector multiplication, but I have no idea how to approach this problem involving the products of row elements. A numerical method would be fine.

Comment: I suspect you'd be better of working with the entrywise logarithms of $A$ and $B$

Comment: This equation is equivalent to $BB^{\mathsf{T}} = A$, so $A$ has to be symmetric. However, this is unusual over $\mathbb{C}$, where the *conjugate* transpose is much more common, and $A$ would have to be Hermitian.

Comment: @Sammy Note that that's a $\prod$, not a $\sum$

Comment: Oh yeah, so logarithms of entries, like I see you've addressed in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

*Partial Answer:*

Let $P$ denote the matrix such that $P_{ij} = \ln(A_{ij})$. If $Q_{ij}$ is a matrix whose entries satisfy
$$
\sum_{k=1}^N Q_{ik} + Q_{jk} = P_{ij} \quad 1 \leq i,j \leq N,\tag{1}
$$
then the matrix $B$ whose entries are $B_{ij} = \exp(Q_{ij})$ will satisfy the original system of equations.

Note that the specific entries of $Q$ don't really matter; all that matters is the row sums. In particular, if $s_j$ denotes the sum of the $j$th row, then system (1) from above amounts to the system
$$
s_i + s_j = P_{ij} \quad 1 \leq i,j \leq N \tag{2}
$$
Given any compatible sums $s_1,\dots,s_N$, the matrix $Q$ can be taken to be any matrix whose $j$th row sums to $s_j$. For instance, we can simply take the $j$th row of $Q$ to be $(s_j,0,\dots,0)$.

System (2) can be written in an elegant matrix form. In particular, let $s$ denote the column-vector $s = (s_1,\dots,s_N)^T$, and let $e \in \Bbb C^N$ denote the all-ones vector. Then system (2) can be rewritten in the form
$$
se^T + es^T = P \tag{3}.
$$